# maven-assembly-plugin is not able to pick up unirest-java as a dependency

Tags: maven, build, maven-assembly-plugin, unirest

I followed the [official doc](http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/) of Unirest-Java and added it as a dependency in my `pom.xml` file.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
    <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16</version>
</dependency>
```

I also have `maven-assembly-plugin` available in the `pom.xml` file so as to package all dependencies in a single jar.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After running `mvn clean compile assembly:single`, I tried to inspect the built jar with `jar tf myapp.jar` and strangely wasn't able to find any unirest class.

After downgrading to a much lower version, everything worked properly.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
    <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Also very curious to know why they renamed the groupId to an odd value like `com.konghq`.

Comment: You should try to use `mvn clean package` instead of `mvn clean compile assembly:singe`....

Comment: I did try that but without any luck.